# Facing issues while getting Root folder's location of ASPNET CORE Web app inside referenced dll

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASPNET Core Web Application which references library that is generated from another .NET Core project. Is there a way to programmatically get the root folder location from within the referenced library? There is a limitation of not passing Root folder path from ASPNET CORE web application to Library's code, So we can not use Dependency injection in this case.

ASPNET Core web application details : Target Framework = .NET Core 3.1

Referenced Library details. Target Framework = .NET Core 3.1

Root folder of ASPNET Core Web app : root folder location is the location where appsettings.json and web.config files are present. for eg : In my windows machine, My application name is Webapp , so the root folder location is : C:\Users\username\source\repos\WebApp\WebApp

// ProcessRootFolder() is the method inside referenced library's code where i want to do some processing with the files present inside ASPNET CORE web app's root folder.

```
using System;

namespace Library
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void ProcessRootFolder()
        {
            //Do some processing with the files present inside ASPNET CORE web app's root folder.
        }

    }
}
```

// ASPNET CORE web app's code from where the Library's method is called.

```
namespace WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            Library.Class1.ProcessRootFolder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is a limitation of not passing Root folder path from ASPNET CORE web application to Library's code" what?

Comment: Yes, I can not ask customer who uses my library's dll to pass the root folder path.

Comment: Do you probably mean to only consider using C# code to call the API method of another project in the current asp.net core project?

Comment: My only purpose is to parse files present inside root folder of ASPNET Core web app from  ProcessRootFolder() method present inside Libraray's dll.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and you want to get the current root path, you could the following code to obtain the current folder:

```
using System;

namespace Library
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void ProcessRootFolder()
        {
            //Do some processing with the files present inside ASPNET CORE web app's root folder.
            string rootFolder = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        }

    }
}
```